# How to handle invalid forms with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

If a form is submitted, I wrap the update logic like this:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // Do update..
} else {
    // ???
}
```

But what if form is not valid? How is it possible to display an error to the user in that case?

The example in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#validating-forms) doesn't even contain an `else`.

Comment: Creating the `formView` and rendering the form should already show the errors.

Comment: else statements are overrated.  The the thing to understand is that $form->handleRequest pulls any data from a posted form.  $form->isValid then adds any errors that it encounters.  Assuming you are using the standard twig template, those errors will then be displayed.

Comment: The form is displayed in a different method from the method which handles it, and redirects back. Therefore I would like to put the error messages to `FlashBag`.

Comment: @IterAtor So what you really asking is how do I pull out error messages from the form view object.  Which is actually an interesting topic but one for which I have no simple answer.  The default work flow allows you to redisplay the form with submitted parameters along with error messages.  Your flash based redirect approach means the user would have to start all over in entering the form data.  In any event, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can display form errors in twig by using `{{ form_errors(your_form_name) }}`

Or loop through errors like this in your twig file (quick example):

```
{% if not your_form_name.vars.valid %}
    {% for child in your_form_name.children %}
        {% for error in child.vars.errors %}
            <span>{{error.message}}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

More information on customising forms here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html